# Extension theorems in Sobolev spaces: Solving for constants

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I saw this problem in PDE book and tried searching for the idea behind solving it which I have not been able to find yet.

If we have $n\ge2$, $B=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:|x|<1\}$ and $B_+=B\cap\{x_n>0\}$. Also, for $u\in C_c^2 (\bar B_+)$, the extension $Eu(x)=u(x)$ if  $x_n>0$ and $Eu(x)=\sum_{j=1}^3 \lambda_j u(x^\prime,{-j\over 3}x_n)$ if  $x_n<0$ defines function $Eu\in C_c^2(B)$. How would you then solve for constants $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$?

Any help or idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: $Eu$ is definitely a function, but you want to know if $Eu$ is $C^2$. Of course the only problem is when $x_n=0$. So you need to check all partial derivatives of $Eu$ agree on $x_n = 0$, and that gives you constraint on $\lambda_i$.

Comment: In particular, for the zeroth derivative, you just put $x_n = 0$ and see that you should have $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 1$.

Comment: So, the sum over $j$ should begin with $j=1$?

Comment: I just saw that. Yes, it should begin with j=1. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preserve the $C^k$ smoothness, the extension process must preserve polynomials of $x_n$ of degrees up to $k$. (Indeed, any change of coefficients of such a polynomial breaks the continuity of its derivatives.)  This requires:

- $\sum_j \lambda_j=1$ to preserve $x_n^0$.
- $\sum_j (j/3)\lambda_j=1$ to preserve $x_n^1$.
- $\sum_j (j/3)^2\lambda_j=1$ to preserve $x_n^2$.

These three linear equations uniquely determine the constants $\lambda_j$, $j=1,2,3$. To verify that the extension indeed preserves the class $C^2$, it's probably easiest to differentiate $Eu$ and check that the derivative is continuous.

You can find examples of such computations on my blog: [Higher-order reflections](http://calculus7.org/2014/07/27/higher-order-reflections/).